# How to redirect on particular url in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am validating a login form using ajax call. It is working great when you enter the wrong information. But if you enter the right credentials nothing happens. I am confused what to do?
sample code:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: URL +'/foo/',
                data: {'uname': name, 'password':pass},
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data["success"] === "false") {
                        //show some message
                        $("#password").val("");
                    }
                                    else {
                                     // here i want to redirect to some url say, /bar/
                                      I am confused how to do it.
                },
                dataType: "json",
            });
            return false
```

Comment: on which event you are validating on submit or for each field by onblur?

Comment: I think he is passing user name and password to the backend and sending success true or false to the UI.

Comment: it is really important to know how he is doing

Comment: @he might be having a button after login and password textboxes.

Comment: @gov after success return i want to redirect to new URL with some POST data. is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

you can use javascript.

```
location.href="new url";
```

it will take you to the new url

```
var querystringParam="sample";

var tempUrl="http://www.test.com?" + "variablettopass=" + querystringParam

location.href=tempUrl;
```

if you have more than one append to query string...

if you want your server name from browser window use this code

```
window.location.hostname
```

but if you do location.href // it will take care...i just gave you for info

Comment: @shamsee , you can do like your url and append it as query string var url="http://www.google.com" + "&valueyouwanttopass=" + dynamicvariable..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.location = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(location).attr("href","url here")
```